# Retificability of a function

Tags: real-analysis

If a function $f$ is monotonous defined in a compact interval say per example $[0,1]$ then its graph is retificable. Can u guys help me out ? I´ve tried to find something to major the function.

Like this :
$ \sum_{n=1}^{N} \sqrt{ (x_{n+1}-x_n)^2 + (f(x_{n+1})-f(x_n))^2} \leq \sum_{n=1}^{N} \sqrt{ (x_{n+1}-x_n)^2} + \sum_{n=1}^{N} \sqrt{{(f(x_{n+1})}-f(x_n))^2}$

but i dont know how to from here.  Im guessing the fact that its monotone should be useful to major the last sum but i dont see where i use the fact that the interval is compact.

Comment: What properties does $f$ have?

Comment: I sorry i forgot to say ill edit the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $f$ is increasing. Let $0 = x_0 < \cdots < x_N = 1$.  I will slightly reindex your sums.

I think it is clear that $$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \sqrt{ (x_{n+1} - x_n)^2 } = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} |x_{n+1} - x_n| = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} (x_{n+1} - x_n) = x_N - x_0 = 1.$$

Since $f$ is increasing you can make essentially the same computation:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \sqrt{ (f(x_{n+1}) - f(x_n))^2 } = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} |f(x_{n+1}) - f(x_n)| = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} (f(x_{n+1}) - f(x_n)) = f(x_N) - f(x_0)$$
which equals $f(1) - f(0)$.

Comment: Oh yeah, thats right i forgot about that trick where the function is increasing, Thanks!!!!